# How can i click specific category element of list in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/ysatish/PycharmProjects/all rules/driver/chromedriver.exe")

driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/men-tshirts")

chali = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li//a[1]//div[2]//div[1]//span')

dak = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li//a[1]//div[2]//div[1]//span[1]')

sub = len(chali)

da = len(dak)

print(da)
print(sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Updated solution:
driver.get('https://www.myntra.com/men-tshirts')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
chali = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[*]//a[1]//div[2]//div[1]//span[1]")))
print(len(chali))
for element in chali:
    print element.text
    element.click()

dak = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li//a[1]//div[2]//div[1]//span")))
print(len(dak))
for element0 in dak:
    print element0.text
element0.click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Updated Solution:**

```
//li[*]//a[1]//div[2]//div[1]//span[not(@class='product-strike')][not(@class='product-discountedPrice')][not(@class='product-discountPercentage')][last()]//span[1]
```

and

```
//li[*]//a[1]//div[2]//div[1]//span
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Buddy i need those elements which have no discount here u shared all  the elements of webpage